# ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Encrypt is not defined

Tags: ionic2

I am using `Ionic 2 rc3`. I am trying to import/include a js file in one of the components.

**ts file**

```
// declare var require: any
'use strict';
// var Encrypt = require('pages/service/jsencrypt.min');
declare var Encrypt: any;
...
this.encrypter = new Encrypt.JSEncrypt();
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="pages/service/jsencrypt.min.js"></script>
```

Before I was using `Ionic 2 beta`, and it was working perfectly when I didn't have anything in `index.html`, and had `var Encrypt = require('pages/service/jsencrypt.min');` at the top of the ts file. Since the upgrade to `rc3`, I cannot seem to get it to import/include the `js` file.

**UPDATE**

In the `jsencrypt.js` file, it has the following code:

```
var JSEncrypt = function (options) {
    options = options || {};
    this.default_key_size = parseInt(options.default_key_size) || 1024;
    this.default_public_exponent = options.default_public_exponent || '010001'; //65537 default openssl public exponent for rsa key type
    this.log = options.log || false;
    // The private and public key.
    this.key = null;
};
```

In my ts file, I need to get a handle on `JSEncrypt`. I used to do the following which worked in the `beta`:

```
this.encrypter = new Encrypt.JSEncrypt();
```

If I try the following:

```
this.encrypter = this.JSEncrypt();
```

I get this error in the CLI:

```
Property 'JSEncrypt' does not exist on type 'PersonService'.
```

How do I get a handle on `JSEncrypt`?

Thanks

Comment: put your library into the "src/assets" folder and then include it in you index.html as "<script src="assets/jsencrypt.min.js"></script>"

Comment: @PrerakTiwari, thanks. I tried that, but get the same error. I have this in my ts file is `declare var Encrypt: any;`. Any suggestions?  In my IDE, if I click in the link `assets/jsencrypt.min.js`, it opens the correct file, so my path seems to be correct.

Comment: I think the problem is related to the `Encrypt` keyword. In the old version, `requires` was assigning a value to it.

Comment: what error are you getting exactly when you compile the code?

Comment: If I use `declare var Encrypt: any;`, I get `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Encrypt is not defined` at run time in the browser console. But if I try access it like `this.JSEncrypt();`, then I get a compile error (see UPDATE above for details).

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing as the user in the link below. But where does `Tree` come from?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472321/how-to-include-external-javascript-library-in-an-ionic-2-typescript-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following steps and for me its working completely fine.

1. Created new Ionic Project using `ionic start MyIonic2Project tutorial --v2 --ts`
2. `cd MyIonic2Project/src/assets` and created a `test.js` file with below code:

   var Test = (function () {
       function Test() {

   ```
   }
   Test.prototype.showAlert = function () {
       alert("Yeee....I am called");
   };
   return Test;
   ```

   }());
3. Then I edited, `MyIonic2Project/src/index.html` and added a "assets/test.js" in the script tag
4. Then i open the **app.componemt.ts** file and declared variable named **Test** just above the class defenetion:
   **declare var Test:any;**
5. Then inside the constructor, I wrote the following code:

   let testVariable = new Test();

   testVariable.showAlert();
6. I ran the code using `ionic serve` command and I am able to see the alert.

Make sure you followed the similar steps in order to make that work. Also make sure that the js library which you are using is correct.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. That worked. I was declaring a variable incorrectly. Should have been:  `this.encrypter = new JSEncrypt();`