# Where to put JavaScript files on an Ionic 2 app?

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

What's the best location to place the auxiliary `JavaScript` files on an `Ionic 2` application? I won't really want to put the source code inside the `www` directory since it is generated automatically.

Below you have a sample of the directory structure of a `Hello World` `Ionic 2` application.

[image]

Comment: src/assets/js/yourjsfile.js and path in index file is<script src="assets/js/yourjsfile.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go one more step inside `pages` folder you can see all of your app pages

ex:

```
--Home
 --home.html
 --home.scss
 --home.ts
```

1. All of your page's view code goes into `.html` file
2. CSS code goes into `.scss` file
3. in ionic 2 we dont directly use javascript. we use type script. and ionic takes care of compiling that code by converting it into javascript.

So our `typescript` code goes into `.ts` fil

Comment: and what about if I need some custom `JavaScript` function like for example: `sprintf`?. Do I still be using `TypeScript` instead `JavaScript`? And what about if I wanna obfuscate the `JavaScript` code?

Comment: if you want to use external js library then  Include the library in index.html and declare its namespace in declarations.d.ts like this
`declare var libraryname: any;`

Comment: could you provide me a link to an example of the usage of an external library?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472321/how-to-include-external-javascript-library-in-an-ionic-2-typescript-project

Comment: since it is not a good idea to use traditional `JavaScript` files but use `TypeScript` files instead..., where is the best location for custom `TypeScript` files like custom classes with custom methods with auxiliary functions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144910/discussion-between-varun-aaruru-and-davidesp).