# include javascripts files to ionic2-angular2 project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, ionic2, calendar

I want to use jquery that needs to include some javascript files  :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.calendars.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.calendars.plus.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.calendars.picker.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.calendars.picker.js"></script>
```

so how can I include these files to ioni2 app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include external Javascript library in an Ionic 2 TypeScript project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472321/how-to-include-external-javascript-library-in-an-ionic-2-typescript-project)

Answer (score 0):

why you are using jquery datepicker ? there is available ionic date picker so you can see how to adding it with this url  https://www.npmjs.com/package/datepicker-for-ionic

Comment: i need hijri date picker for ionic2 and angular2