# Is it possible to use Cleave.js in an Ionic App?

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm fairly new to Ionic and i'm looking to add some input formatting (credit cards, phone numbers) and came across [Cleave.js](https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/) and was curious if it is possible to use with an Ionic App.

Comment: Not sure on the particulars of that library, but here's a general solution on getting it into your project.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472321/how-to-include-external-javascript-library-in-an-ionic-2-typescript-project

Comment: May you can install it throug npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cleave